# Reverse proxy a subdirectory to a website expecting to be in the root

Tags: docker, subdomain, reverse-proxy, subdirectory, caddy

I am using Caddy to provide SSL/HTTPS and then reverse proxying various url subdirectories to various websites/servers running on various local ports - mostly docker containers.

So:

```
https://example.org goes to localhost
https://example.org/calendar goes to localhost:8090
https://example.org/address goes to localhost:8091
https://example.org/files goes to localhost:8092
```

etc...

However some of the sites/services assume they hosted in the root domain and use absolute URL's so while the index.html pages are being served up OK for all the subdirectories/apps, links to CSS etc are all being routed to example.org/css etc rather than example.org//css

I want to avoid having to edit all the html/apps or using subdomains instead of subdirectories...

Any ideas how I might get around this issue?

Answer (score -2):

You can use pattern matching to get this done. Here is an example caddy config file:

```
example.org {
    reverse_proxy / localhost
    reverse_proxy /calendar/* localhost:8090
    reverse_proxy /address/* localhost:8091
    reverse_proxy /files/* localhost:8091
}
```

You can find more details here: https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/matchers

Comment: Thanks for your input - but that is what I'm already doing. The problem is the proxied pages are returning HTML that includes absolute links (like '/css/whatever.css') these are then served from localhost rather than (say) localhost:8090... which gives 404's. I need to 'fix' the returned html - to use relative links, or some such...

Comment: Yup, you can fix your links to follow the relative paths and that should solve your issue. Depending on your application as well as using PHP you can always rewrite the URL path accordingly as well.

Comment: Cheers Aditya, my original question was whether anyone knew of an app or similar to do this - so I don't have to edit every app individualy...

Comment: I got it. But that would be something of middleware of sorts that you can specify in your app. That's is what Caddy actually does for you. What you can do to automate this would be to add a script to rewrite the caddy file if new routes/microservices are added to the app.